Assembly code problem : invalid use of register
I am trying to write a function in assembly (x86_64) that returns the scalar product of two vectors (signed chars). The two first arguments of the function are the two vectors and the third one is their length. Here is my code :
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text
.global produit_scalaire
.type produit_scalaire, @function

produit_scalaire:
   PUSH RBP                     / Save the value of RBP
   MOV RBP, RSP                 / Set up the stack frame
   CMP RDX, 0                   / Check if RDX (the counter) is zero
   JE vecteurs_vides            / Jump to the label 'vecteurs_vides' if it is
   MOV RAX, 0                   / Initialize RAX to zero
   
boucle:

   / Check if we haven't finished (if yes, jump to the 'fin' label)
   CMP RDX, 0
   JE fin
   
   PUSH RBX                     / Save the value of RBX (for calling conventions)
   PUSH RAX                     / Save the value of RAX

   
   / Perform the multiplication of the corresponding elements
   MOV AL, byte ptr [RDI]       / Load the element from the first vector
   IMUL byte ptr [RSI]          / Multiply it by the corresponding element from the second vector
   
   / Retrieve the saved values and add the calculated product to RAX
   POP RBX                      / Retrieve the value of RBX
   ADD RAX, RBX                 / Add it to RAX
   POP RBX                      / Retrieve the value of RBX
   

   
   / Increment the pointers of RDI and RSI to move to the next integer
   INC RDI                      / Increment the pointer of the first vector
   INC RSI                      / Increment the pointer of the second vector
   DEC RDX                      / Decrement the counter
   
   JMP boucle                   / Jump back to the beginning of the loop
   
   
vecteurs_vides:
   MOV RAX, 0                   / Set RAX to zero (if both vectors are empty)
fin:
   POP RBP                      / Restore the value of RBP
   RET                          / Return from the function

A C program that uses this function is
#include <stdio.h>

int produit_scalaire(char *, char *, int);

int main()
{
   char v1[] = {1, 2, 6};
   char v2[] = {1, 2, 3};
   int n = 3;
   
   printf("Produit scalaire = %d", produit_scalaire(v1, v2, n));
}

The error I get is
produit_scalaire.s: Assembler messages:
produit_scalaire.s:19: Error: invalid use of register
produit_scalaire.s:20: Error: invalid use of register


Is there a problem with my PUSH instructions ? I don't understand why it doesn't work... Thanks in advance for your help !

What assembler are you using?

I am using GCC. My command is : gcc -Wall -O3 -o produit_scalaire produit_scalaire_test.c produit_scalaire.s

Then all of your line comment characters should be '#'

I did it and I got this :

produit_scalaire.s: Assembler messages:
produit_scalaire.s: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
/usr/bin/ld: warning: /tmp/ccyggbUc.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
/usr/bin/ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker

Those are warnings. To fix the first obviously put a newline at the end.

I the class I think they wrote the comments with '/', but maybe there are different ways to achieve it...

I added a new line and in fact I still have : /usr/bin/ld: warning: /tmp/ccuRDgqU.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
/usr/bin/ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker

That's still a warning. If you want to fix that you need to add such a section at the end: .section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits

Thank you very much, it works !!! Thus was my problem the comments ?

Yes.  Incomprehensible error message, like many gcc error messages.

It's technically gnu assembler not gcc :) That said it's strange that it only complained about those two lines and not the rest. My version complains already the first time the / comment is used (line 7).

Yes and it's way more difficult to find documentation about assembly than other languages like C... Your answers where very helpful !

The GNU assembler manual is https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ .  You're right, it's not as well documented as the ISO C standard language.  (There isn't just one assembly language; every assembler is different even for the same ISA, although some like GAS and clang are essentially compatible.)  According to https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dChars.html  / is a comment character unless --divide has been specified, then it's the division operator.  e.g. mov eax, 11/2.  But I thought  --divide was on by default: that assembles to mov eax, 5 not mov eax, 11

But if / is the first non-whitespace character on a line, gcc -c foo.s does ignore the line (treating it as a "line comment").  Like /  nop xyz which is an error without the /.  Ok, by default at least, / only works for line comments when it appears at the start of a line, not following an instruction.  The normal comment character for x86 is #, like inc eax   # i++

Re: the need for .note.GNU-stack - the toolchain defaults disable hardening features unless all object files opt in.  You normally want this, so it warns if you use the default instead of explicitly making the stack executable.  See Why data and stack segments are executable? / Unexpected exec permission from mmap when assembly files included in the project for examples of why this is worthy of a warning.
